# How can i create an alert in OMS when a windows service is stopped?

Tags: azure, azure-oms

I need OMS to trigger an alert when a service is stopped for example the IIS service. Can someone advise the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i worked it out myself

To get this list you need to go to **advanced analytics** in your OMS workspace then run the query as below

```
search EventLog == "System"
| where ( EventLevelName == "Information" )
| where ( Computer == "server1" )
```

This then shows a list of other fields, i found the ParameterXml field contained what i needed ie the keywords "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and "stopped". I then added this to the above query to filter out where the service called IIS (World Wide Web Publishing) stopped

```
search EventLog == "System"
| where ( EventLevelName == "Information" )
| where ( Computer == "server1" )
| where ParameterXml == "<Param>World Wide Web Publishing Service</Param><Param>stopped</Param><Param>-</Param>"
```

All you need to do then is create an alert and set your conditions

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Change Tracking" solution for this:
ConfigurationChange | where ConfigChangeType == "WindowsServices" and SvcName == "W3SVC" and SvcState != "Running"

Then to alert once back up:
ConfigurationChange | where ConfigChangeType == "WindowsServices" and SvcName == "W3SVC" and SvcState == "Running"